# Query for Java toolchain details in Bazel

Tags: bazel, bazel-java, bazel-query

I'd like to use `bazel query` to get more details about the Java toolchain. Specifically Java source level to be used.

From the `java_library` target I was able to query for the Java toolchain:

```
  rule_input: "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_toolchain"
  rule_input: "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:java_plugins_flag_alias"
  rule_input: "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:proguard_whitelister"
  rule_input: "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_type"
```

What query can I use to get the source level the target is using?

I tried `bazel query "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_toolchain" --output=proto` but the output doesn't seem to contain that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task lies fundamentally outside the capabilities of `query` because the Java toolchain is not selected until after loading, the phase `query` operates on. (In particular, `query` cannot consider `--java_language_version` or other command line flags.) However, [`cquery`](https://bazel.build/query/cquery) can accomplish the task:

```
$ bazel cquery "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_toolchain" --output starlark --starlark:expr 'providers(target)["JavaToolchainInfo"].source_version'
11
```

Keep in mind that a complex build could use multiple Java toolchains, leaving your inquiry ill-defined.

Comment: Is there any breaking change in Bazel 7 which would break this query? Looks like the new Starlark expression needs to be `"providers(target)['@@_builtins//:common/java/java_toolchain.bzl%JavaToolchainInfo'].source_version"`

Comment: FWIW, I ended up with this code to query for all the infos needed. https://github.com/salesforce/bazel-eclipse/blob/888bcd333ac7bd4166fdb411562b74c2b54514d5/bundles/com.salesforce.bazel.eclipse.core/src/com/salesforce/bazel/eclipse/core/model/discovery/BaseProvisioningStrategy.java#L942